# SPARQL - Get especific values

Tags: sparql, owl

I new in SPARQL, and I need to query an ontology to get some values from it:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_1943">
    <rdfs:label rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">telogen effluvium</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/DOID_987"/>
    <oboInOwl:id rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">DOID:1943</oboInOwl:id>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ICD9CM:704.02</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">SNOMEDCT_2010_1_31:201147004</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">SNOMEDCT_2010_1_31:39479004</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
    <oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Telogen effluvium (disorder)</oboInOwl:hasExactSynonym>
    <oboInOwl:hasDbXref rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">UMLS_CUI:C0263518</oboInOwl:hasDbXref>
    <oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">disease_ontology</oboInOwl:hasOBONamespace>
</owl:Class>
```

I need to select the owl class (DOID_1943) and, obtain the label (telogen effluvium) also the snomed codes (SNOMEDCT_2010_1_31:201147004 and SNOMEDCT_2010_1_31:39479004).

I'm doing this:

```
    select distinct ?x ?a 
where {
?x <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref> ?a 
}
```

But not working, even when i get the data i want, its not associated with the owl class.

Answer (score 0):

Found:

```
select distinct ?x ?label
where {
?x <http://www.geneontology.org/formats/oboInOwl#hasDbXref> "SNOMEDCT_2010_1_31:33176006" . ?x  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?label
}
```